# How to change real name with exim?

Tags: exim

When I send an email through `exim`, I get a `From` line that looks something like this:

```
From: smith <smith@example.com>
      ^^^^^
```

How do I get `exim` to change the part marked above?

I can change the email address using the conf's rewrite section, but can't figure out how to change the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [34.8 Flags controlling the rewriting process](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_34.html#SEC748), use the `w` flag to rewrite the entire field rather than just the email part:

> Sometimes there is a need to replace the whole address item, and this can be done by adding the flag letter 'w' to a rule. If this is set on a rule that causes an address in a header to be rewritten, the entire address is replaced, not just the working part. The replacement must be a complete RFC 822 address, including the angle brackets if necessary.